Curl PHP recaptcha verify
I am trying to use CURL to veify a recaptcha.
When I make the inquiry in POSTMAN it works.
When I make the identical inquiry using CURL, I get "invalid-input-response" from the www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify.
I changed the query from a x-www-form-upload to the default, and targeted "localhost/f.php" that dumps the $_POST variables.  My intent was to see what was getting received.
I noticed that the "response" field received is truncated, which would account for my error.   I'm looking for what I need to do to have the entire field length passes.
    $jdata["secret"] = $recaptcha_secret_key;
    $jdata["response"] = $recaptcha_response;
    $jdata["remoteip"] = "111.111.111.111"; // Actual IP masked
    $json_params=json_encode($jdata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print "<pre>$json_params</pre>\n";
    $ch = curl_init("localhost/f.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);   // TLS 1.2
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/html"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_params);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

The receiving form:
<h1>Form Vars</h1>
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $n => $v) { $s=strlen($n); print "Len=$s P=$n V=$v<br>\n"; }
?>
<h2>Done</h2>

And the output:
Form Vars
S3=2070 P={ ____"secret":_"actualkeymasked", ____"response":_"03AFcWeA5vynnqRYr6oP-iela92Jjz2u4FHD79DtUNmEUo_h636eUecKPg_S3WSfF41TiebRgEoWE0epnGb2UAVgudxZ1dZhl8WC6uoNeRvPNaqsnqEHyUxovpNgbeEXJ3oPEpp6uMQV1W4L9x1t9jL1gpbErcFF8cwIy3NGQVfL6yCJ_qMFvqq4mPEStRzTccRMTlqrD9YQ6Hqe2IFH6TDhROzKSX4S3NRaxRBaqErBRcXMqN2yEJhuqVyJY4NBsyqeLsh4aXMgxkbIgXR6CivK3k44lBZfhvEA5-VsQCLaWsPgAak91BeJacI7CigFylfMiv50o_lROif3UFmIhuuU4y6JxGqkTQwtOAtZBQuuFJ-t7SzDE5ou69fWkrjFhs591pqX_mzTNGIjoafMPBBBfeMGphvrCygO1MJXi4VZxBJ3CDQWw6-NNfalEMcZ9SMgzYTT2yhkPvvLmfGup7zpsJ-6tEhydJB3uLbPwAnqFlDTSyYNZRJJ_16KtW7TMNks2ez-81mv67PO1acLp4inTfem3swuzEWYoSW1OY-xfto8BCKPyHwWIsbxs-DHzEqtc7S-vfY2xP-AsTB3jlDnmZdwQ-w139i-8u4Szh-PNqH22KQpCc2aAZEjtrUKaCKWRwGELdlLr_p6eZ6YWT2Ak3njN994o0OPy5I_z5mGkpsCh6DA6LsssPYjzF5FmKy22RMXFtZPvwxbrAGbk-Y1Vqn7lFs01V5A1FlPnvJZ0Q0oU3j8C14wNQmvm8XJimENzv-FD0Ov1wEqexg41026R0-iPmsBeO1pn_kIumhyr73UzwAbmBwnEgwgOJbDntElPZ-Rdi9WciqixB-H5eFfmjAcemFmtBPo0QT2G6sIEX9fVRNRD5Ir2M1khxZE2xvYJm5IQbhNfNL2JyyInGrHJSZOWkVnrDwrSLq4ftiKVtF9CwhKgp9QCFcC0Koccmrs-i1Uue2yL5CRhrr-XX_QNZTgno8tJ66VJ1GPWWeYVctADZcKSy4hWR0Nd9W39LjVxFdbfbPenbbLkyBiFPB-bm8NlZWuVOkSAnhTimt0QGqAqEPrqjv7vgf8bdO11TYAuvzORAsBo1imhKujQ6ZA0sOh_GbYE9xV8ghmIA_DuTtEshfUZO0TlABwcD7n5o5bKuQwO9MEAmDft1lDe2kgY_6KEOvBCysWjXi0MxFfntyLjidWcx2KriT0ybGnP8Z2rWfeBsfrcLl20Bw62h7p7TLGIzmZiblZIt4b5B30GY4bV9zZ8WN-d1P4kIQAvkWzaSWCd2iNlTfX8PfAkdXL7c6Yxf3x4dS6kn8p3WDP_XhEymvGk6EOUsNlunUEt65SG_rFQrSEiKhQSehr8Sa4YLoEPLnIRBGxYfnfYOReXSXYvPTY0omhyENPeFNKj--sFgRrG1Bt20eLYZwwhOIh02uvhP9fXM3Rt2xLNGAMmcYbxNKmhlo4k8gaqofZXf-CLYfmZxxAefVg5wGzJDn67rXwcmSBG7P7ll8JXPime2t5OYCFpEStYmUjCggoVS-umyF1Bbxbi_qbDzz8nq6cSFizlR-5Ylsn2y3Xg_-2r4Ht2Qj3qGHlpC28wweH2k5zNmBF3CqENHcda1Mkua8YtrT7K_8XSKE-cv-zyksE7nIZyiehACsnyteSk_XuCLTX7bZNtIrOQLCfprYgD8lP_EXjkF3SQ8bdL9R-UsAeuwRvxi2IiLHZ8Uw_fnmyMjkt9HAmNz44lngzvJqFLXOGveIDSt2pETFxY_fwgHblqxi5doJMu6gP0KZd0q6xE45vYvoeTEKgYRa4u_uKmnpmLiyhWZFAcBCioc-M-J62gBG8milYLsUPzQ5aUB7AwwXpLxuNAhNBGbX5kntemU-PZBI7dGj257e60_mPv3WhZt7r-wynXsiKvr0TiiNzk80Wf3vVZlV4C4R9OnkLuoFiv8GkgK_4wXAA", ____"remoteip":_"actual ip masked" } V=
Done

I'd like to know why I am getting a truncated value of "response" back.

Specifying Content-Type: text/html makes no sense at all when you're sending JSON data. Content-Type: application/json ought to be correct for that. Hopefully you know the difference between HTML and JSON? And then read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php for how to read and parse that incoming JSON data in the receiving PHP script.

When I make the inquiry in POSTMAN it works...did you use the feature in Postman which will auto-generate equivalent PHP code for you? That should have saved you some time, but it looks like maybe you didn't take advantage of that.

Bad paste - used  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded"));

OK. But that's still wrong when you're sending JSON. It still all needs amending as per my first comment.

Or if, as seems to be the case from the documentation the google service actually requires you to send form-url-encoded data, then keep your curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded")); line, but change $json_params=json_encode($jdata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); so it prepares form-url-encoded data instead of JSON data! (Hint: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). Again, make sure you know the difference between these various data formats (e.g. form-encoded, JSON, XML, HTML etc).

I managed to get it to work:
$jdata["secret"] = $recaptcha_secret;
$jdata["response"] = $recaptcha_response;
$jdata["remoteip"] = $ip;

$ch=curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);   // TLS 1.2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($jdata));
$output = curl_exec($ch);


It seems that you need to pass those params within the URL even if you are using POST. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET&respnose=RESPONSE

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
